# How to open input windows after another in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: Screenshot] Is there a *simple* way to have your programm open an input windows after the last one was closed? I want to input 200 parameters and the programm should not open 200 windows at the same time but only one at a time.
(I just started Python, so if this is to complicated, just tell me)

Comment: Hi, what GUI toolkit/library are you using? Can you post the part of the code that opens the input window?

Comment: @solarc I use JetBrains PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.5. I will add a screenshot to the original post.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code. Include actual code in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I see the error now. You are creating multiple Tk() windows in a while loop and then running `mainloop()` at the end, which will show the windows that have been created all at once.

The easy solution would be to include the mainloop inside the while loop. Like this:

```
while i < 9:
    master = Tk()
    # setup the window
    mainloop()
```

So when you close the window, mainloop will finish and the loop will start again and create a new window.

There's another issue though, your check for `l == i` will always be false (on the first run `i` will be `0` and `l` will be 1, so i will never increment and `i < 9` will always be true and the while loop will continue infinitely). Why don't you use a range instead?

```
for i in range(9):
    master = Tk()
    # setup the window
    mainloop()
```